# Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, soap, fatal-error

I'm trying a simple web service example and I get this error even though I uncommented `extension=php_soap.dll` in the `php.ini` file:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\server.php on line 2

Comment: Are you sure you edited Apache/bin/php.ini and restarted apache after that??

Comment: Thank you. Apperantly, I changed another php.ini file. I found the one in Apache file.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0 for those of you who haven't installed it yet

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-soap` (plus `service apache2 restart`) fixed this issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 415, accepted):

**Diagnose**

Look up the following inside your script file

```
phpinfo();
```

If you can't find `Soap Client` set to `enabled` like so:
[image: the way soap should appear in phpinfo()]

**Fix**

Do the following:

1. Locate `php.ini` in your **apache** bin folder, I.e `Apache/bin/php.ini`
2. Remove the `;` from the beginning of `extension=php_soap.dll`
3. Restart your Apache server
4. Look up your `phpinfo();` again and check if you see a similar picture to the one above
5. If you do, problem solved!

On the other hand if this doesn't solve your issue, you may want to check the [requirements for SOAP here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php). Also in the comment section you can find good advice on connecting to https.

Comment: Don't forget to also uncomment this line: `;extension=php_openssl.dll` 
if the WSDL you are trying to reach is under https protocol

Comment: in my case it was not installed and there is no extension=php_soap.dll in the php.in um using php5.6 centos6.9

Comment: I am using xamp and just uncommenting `extension=soap` do the trick.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap for those of you who haven't installed it yet

Comment: php -i | grep Soap using the the command line on linux systems.

Comment: If it doesn't work maybe you need install soap first : sudo apt install php5.6-soap . Then restart apache

Comment: For me, The `SoapClient` class is still not found. I see it enabled in the phpinfo(), the extension is enabled, openssl is enabled too, everything is ok but the class isn't found. I use Wampserver 3.0 and PHP 5.6 and I restarted Apache but doesn't solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: I am using xampp. I did not have `extension=php_soap.dll` in my file. I just added this line of text and it worked.

Comment: How I can enable in shared server?

Comment: I restarted `my computer` for set variable!

Comment: If I follow the above comment (`apt-get install php7.0-soap`) on Ubuntu 20.04.01, I get this error: Unable to locate package php7.0-soap.  Running `apt-get install php-soap` fixes the issue and installs the appropriate soap version for this OS (7.4 in my case).

Answer (score 181):

To install SOAP in PHP-7 run following in your Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap
```

To install SOAP in PHP-7.1 run following in your Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-soap
```

To install SOAP in PHP-7.2 run following in your Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap
```

To install SOAP in PHP-7.3 run following in your Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-soap
```

Comment: Also be sure to run sudo service apache2 reload

Comment: In my case it was `sudo apt-get install php-soap`

Comment: i had upgraded to php7 and had forgotten to reinstall php70w-soap (i always completely remove old version of PHP)

Comment: What to do if i want to install php7.3-soap :-)? I am lost.

Comment: @chris did you try: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap`

Comment: You also have to uncomment `extension=soap` in your php.ini file (remove the `;`)

Comment: Getting this error:

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-soap'

Comment: @ParminderSingh can you try `sudo apt-get install php-soap`

Comment: @Nahid thanks, I tried that but it did not work and did not show it as installed soap package then I installed it by extracting the soap package directly from the url and it worked.

Comment: `php-soap` is the generic package name on Debian, which automatically maps to the installed PHP version (at least the default one)

Comment: For php 7.4 you can use `sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap`

Answer (score 21):

For AWS (RHEL):

```
sudo yum install php56-soap
```

(56 here is 5.6 PHP version - put your version here).

Comment: This might be `sudo yum install php56w-soap`! I forgot the w, and this installs, and still it didn't work. It took a while to figure this out but now it works.

Comment: For me it was sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap

Comment: No need for version, just php-soap

Comment: I had to use sudo yum install php56-php-soap. I am using multi-version PHP with php7.2 as default and php5.6 configured via php-fpm.

Answer (score 18):

To install SOAP in PHP5.6 run following in your Ubuntu 14.04 terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap
service php5.6-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

See if SOAP was enabled:

```
php -m
```

(You should see SOAP between returned text.)

Answer (score 12):

For **XAMPP users**, open `php.ini` file located in `C:/xampp/php` and remove the `;` from the beginning of `extension=soap`. Then restart Apache and that's it!

Answer (score 11):

I had to run

```
php-config --configure-options --enable-soap
```

as root and restart apache.

That worked! Now my phpinfo() call shows the SOAP section.

Comment: `reboot` should be mentioned that its apache reboot, not server reboot.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this issue on PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 nginx

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-soap

sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 8):

I **couln't find** the `SOAP` section in `phpinfo()` so I had to install it.

For information the `SOAP` extension requires the `libxml` PHP extension. This means that passing in `--enable-libxml` is also required according to http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php

**From WHM panel**

1. Software » Module Installers » PHP Extensions & Applications Package
2. Install SOAP 0.13.0

   WARNING: "pear/HTTP_Request" is deprecated in favor of "pear/HTTP_Request2"

   install ok: channel://pear.php.net/SOAP-0.13.0
3. Install HTTP_Request2 (optional)

   install ok: channel://pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2
4. Restart Services » HTTP Server (Apache)

**From shell command**

1.pear install SOAP

2.reboot

Comment: WHM's EasyApache interface also has an option for enabling Soap in the Exhaustive Options list.

Answer (score 6):

For Docker* add this line:

```sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap
```

**: For debian based images, ie. won't work for alpine variants.*

Answer (score 4):

For PHP 7.4 & Docker
add this line in Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libxml2-dev \

RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
```

Rebuild the image and restart ;)

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 7.8 and PHP 7.3

```
yum install php-soap
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

**With wamp server and php 8 :**

**Right-click on the WampServer icon in the system tray.**
[image]

**Enable the SOAP extension:**

Go to "PHP Extensions" (or a similar option) and make sure that the SOAP extension is checked or enabled.

[image]

**Restart WampServer services:**

Right-click on the WampServer icon and select "Restart All Services."

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit `nusoap.php` class and put it in your project directory, you can download it from the [Internet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

Use this code:

```
require_once('nusoap.php');
```

Comment: NuSoap create an Web Service (server). The initial question is for consume an WebService (client), so there are no relation between NuSoap and the mentioned problem

Comment: perhaps you where thinking something at the moment of working with nusoap that is why you cemmented this.

Comment: "The Internet."

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 8:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install php8.0-soap
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the ***Symfony cache*** was causing the problem,
after running `composer install` the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was due to the scope and solved by replacing `new SoapClient` by `new \SoapClient`.