# PHP Error Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, cs-cart

I was trying to install Wordpress on our server to test, but in order to do that I had to upgrade our current PHP version to 5.3. I upgraded our PHP and I am now finding that our Purolator shipping module is no longer working. According to our host support the "purolator.php" file is missing data that the new version of PHP requires. Unfortunately, I can't revert our PHP version back and our programmer is away.

This is the error message I was able to get from our website host support team:

```
tail /var/www/vhosts/phantomcables.com/statistics/logs/error_log -f 
[Thu Jul 19 08:34:28 2012] [error] [client 70.51.168.201] PHP Fatal 
error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in 
/var/www/vhosts/phantomcables.com/httpdocs/shippings/purolator.php on line 
49, referer: https://phantomcables.com/index.php?dispatch=checkout.cart
```

These are lines 40 to 72:

```
function createPWSSOAPClient()
{
    /** Purpose : Creates a SOAP Client in Non-WSDL mode with the appropriate authentication and 
    *           header information
    **/
    //Set the parameters for the Non-WSDL mode SOAP communication with your Development/Production credentials
    //echo DIR_SHIPPING_FILES."estimatingservice.wsdl";

    $url = "https://webservices.purolator.com/PWS/V1/Estimating/EstimatingService.asmx";
    $client = new SoapClient( DIR_SHIPPING_FILES."estimatingservice.wsdl", 
                              array (
                                        'trace'         =>  true,
                                        'location'      =>  $url,
                                        'uri'           =>  "http://purolator.com/pws/datatypes/v1",
                                        'login'         =>  PRODUCTION_KEY,
                                        'password'      =>  PRODUCTION_PASS
                                    )
                            );

    //Define the SOAP Envelope Headers
    $headers[] = new SoapHeader ( 'http://purolator.com/pws/datatypes/v1', 'RequestContext', 
                                  array (
                                            'Version'           =>  '1.0',
                                            'Language'          =>  'en',
                                            'GroupID'           =>  'xxx',
                                            'RequestReference'  =>  'Rating Example'
                                       )
                                ); 
    //Apply the SOAP Header to your client                            
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);

    return $client;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a pretty specific error, the [SoapClient](http://us2.php.net/soapclient) class isn't defined - You / your host probably removed or disabled it when you upgraded.

Comment: Do you have any kind of config file, or something named autoload?

Comment: thank you nickb, i will try to call our support team and see if they can re-enable it or re-install it.

Comment: my apologies kevinmajor1, where would i find this config file. i do have a config.php but i believe it is part of the CS-Cart software that we are running our site on.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you did not have installed the **php-soap** package on your server.
Type

```
phpinfo();
```

in your code and check if 'Soap Client' is 'enabled'.
If not, I don't know your distribution and package manager, but here is the code for Fedora I use:

```
$ yum install php-soap
```

I suggest to do it with your programmer back or a sys admin by your sides, you never know what could happen. A backup is also useful before any installation!

Comment: so i just got off the phone with our web host support team. and they did notice that SOAP was not enabled on our site, she enabled it and also changed the "PHP Support to run as" from Apache module to FastCGI application, unfortunately. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: So we reverted back to an older version of PHP, and re-enabled SOAP. apparently that was the issue, not sure why that didn't work with the newer version of PHP.

Again thank you for all of your help. This is a great community.

Comment: For those who do not have the right repos on CentOS: Google the epel and remi repos, and add them.

Comment: I restarted `my computer` for set variable!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add (or remove any comment characters before)

```
extension=soap.so
```

to your `php.ini` file, and then restart the web server.

If you are having trouble finding your `php.ini` file, create a page with the following:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

and load that file in your browser.

On some systems, this setting may not actually live in `php.ini`. For example, if you are using Zend Server, the setting would live in `/usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/soap.ini`.

Comment: So we reverted back to an older version of PHP, and re-enabled SOAP. apparently that was the issue, not sure why that didn't work with the newer version of PHP.

Again thank you for all of your help. This is a great community.

Answer (score 1):

So we reverted back to an older version of PHP, and re-enabled SOAP. apparently that was the issue, not sure why that didn't work with the newer version of PHP.

Again thank you for all of your help. This is a great community.

Answer (score 1):

It is already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Do the following:

- Locate php.ini in your apache bin folder, I.e Apache/bin/php.ini
- Remove the ; from the beginning of extension=php_soap.dll
- Restart your Apache server
- Look up your phpinfo(); again and check if you see a similar picture to the one above

If you do, problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

Enable the SOAP extension, require it in your composer.json like so:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-soap": "*"
  }
}
```