# PHP: Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, apache, soap

First of all, I've read this question ([Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)) and have everything done the answer says. But still experience an issue.

I also found similar issue here (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64445) but it is not solved there too.

I'm trying to set up a PHP + Apache environment on Win 7 64.

1. **PHP**: php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x86. Thread safe.
2. **Apache**: httpd-2.4.10-win32-VC11

So, here is my `C:\PHP\php.ini` for SOAP. Everything is set correctly:

```
extension=php_soap.dll

; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; On windows:
extension_dir = "C:/PHP/ext"

[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-enabled
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1

; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-dir
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"

; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used
; instead of original one.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-ttl
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

; Sets the size of the cache limit. (Max. number of WSDL files to cache)
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
```

In `C:/PHP/ext` folder I have `php_soap.dll` file, `C:\PHP\ext\php_soap.dll`.

But my `phpinfo();` returns *ONLY* this about SOAP:

[image]

I *DO NOT* have these settings shown:

[image]

And I get error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\myApp\src\Em\Bundle\PlatformBundle\Services\MyAppService.php on line 46
```

What did I miss? How to solve it?

Answer (score 11):

This is very easy.

You work with Symfony2 i think and you use namespaces. This function is in the Root-Namespace.

use:

```
\SoapClient()
```

Otherwise you are in the namespace and they can't find the class.

You have the same Problem with the `Exception` class for example.

Comment: That's right, I had `SoapClient()` class call without \. I put `\SoapClient()` but the issue remains

Comment: This is an especially stupid thing to research because of the confusion between Soap WSDL/XML Namespace and PHP Namespace. Thanks for the interpreting that correctly

Comment: For future Laravel users, also for you too, as Laravel uses Symfony. `use SoapClient;`

Answer (score 6):

If you are on linux and you are missing the soap extension, like I was and you have already enabled it in php.ini then try

```
apt-get install php-soap
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in a custom module Drupal 8.

It uses Symfony2 so just add this in controller :

```
use SoapClient;
```

Answer (score 2):

**in PHP/7.4.11 Server**

In XAMPP Control Panel

1. Stop Apache Server
2. Click on Config next to Apache
3. From dropdown select PHP (php.ini)
4. Ctrl+F to find ***;extension=soap*** and remove ; from the line.
5. Ctrl+S to save the file.
6. Start Apache again.

this steps solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try config the extension using the path:

```
extension=ext/php_soap.dll
```

In `phpinfo()` you can see this important lines:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   C:\Apache24\bin\php.ini
```

But you can change the ini folder if desire in httpd.conf:

```
# configure the path to php.ini
#PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

BUT SEE what extension dir are you using:

```
extension_dir   C:\php
```

In the "Core" section. This can be configured too.