# soap class not found in local

Tags: php, sms, soap-client

I've got this :

```
try{
    $soap = new SoapClient("https://www.ovh.com/soapi/soapi-re-1.8.wsdl");
    $session = $soap->login("$nic", "$pass","fr", false);
    $result = $soap->telephonySmsSend($session, "$sms_compte", "$from", "$to", "$message", "", "1", "", "");
    $soap->logout($session);
}catch(SoapFault $fault){
    echo $fault;
}
```

The problem is that i've got an error telling me that the class SoapClient is not found.
How to create it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following inside your PHP script file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you can't find Soap Client set to enabled like so:

[image]

Do the following:

1.) Locate php.ini in your apache bin folder, I.e Apache/bin/php.ini

2.) Remove the ; from the beginning of extension=php_soap.dll

3.) Restart your Apache server

4.) Look up your phpinfo();

Don't forget to also uncomment this line: `;extension=php_openssl.dll` if the `WSDL` you are trying to reach is under `https` protocol
  again and check if you see  a similar picture to the one above

If you do, problem solved!

**In case if you does not find `SOAP` section in `phpinfo()`**

For information the SOAP extension requires the libxml PHP extension. This means that passing in --enable-libxml is also required according to http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php

**From WHM panel**

.Software » Module Installers » PHP Extensions & Applications Package

.Install SOAP 0.13.0

WARNING: "pear/HTTP_Request" is deprecated in favor of "pear/HTTP_Request2"

install ok: channel://pear.php.net/SOAP-0.13.0

.Install HTTP_Request2 (optional)

install ok: channel://pear.php.net/HTTP_Request2

.Restart Services » HTTP Server (Apache)

**From shell command**

1.) pear install SOAP

2.) Reboot

Comment: I'm in local, i don't have the file php.ini

Comment: check the server root folder. In Xampp > PHP (if you are using xampp) folder there must be a php.ini file

Comment: I'm using a wamp server with phpeasy

Comment: find in your system a file named as 'php.ini' and BTW what is phpeasy?

Comment: it's to create  a wamp server

Comment: Thank you i found it but now i don't receive the sms

Comment: Welcome, then please approve my answer as right answer So that any other person can get the help easily.

Answer (score 1):

We have Nginx with Fedora 20 realise I have installed soap with following command.

```
yum install php-soap
```

Then I went to php.ini to un-comment soap extension. It was not there so, I added my own following line.

extension=soap.so
Then i restart server with following command

service nginx restart

Good luck:)