# How to login Five9 through API

Tags: php, soap, five9

Im new to Five9 i got some sample code in GitHub (https://github.com/kielerrr/Five9 ) which i went though the code and i passed the credentials into API but i get the following error

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Five9-master\includes\Five9.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Five9-master\contacts\getContactRecords.php(12): f9->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Five9-master\includes\Five9.php on line 20"

```
   $wsdl_five9 = "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v4/AdminWebService?wsdl&user=User_ID";
   //$wsdl_five9 = "https://api.five9.com/wsadmin/v4/AdminWebService?wsdl";
   try {
        $soap_options = array('login' => 'uer_name', 'password' => 'mypassword', 'trace' => true);
        $this->_connection = new SoapClient($wsdl_five9, $soap_options);//20th line 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $error_message."ERROR";
        exit;
    }
```

Please help me to go through this ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Comment: yes need to enable soap extension in my system php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Above code works fine need to enable soap in your system .
locate your php.ini file and Un-comment(remove semicolon before soap extension)as below. 
change from :
";extension=php_soap.dl"
to :
"extension=php_soap.dll" .