# Want to integrate Alfresco With PHP

Tags: php, alfresco

I want to upload files into alfresco by using PHP code.
I am using [this code](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.0a/root/modules/php-sdk/source/php/remote/Tutorials/BasicTutorial5-Exercise1.php)

But it is giving this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\alfresco_php\php-lib\source\php\api\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php on line 21

Can anyone help me how to integrate Alfresco in PHP?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code instead of a link to your code.

Comment: The PHP soap library is missing. You will have to install/enable it in your xampp installation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found

Comment: thank you i found the solution for this error