# Laravel and SoapClient - Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: laravel, soap

For some reason I don't manage to use SoapClient, even though (as you can see on the image) it is well referenced

[image]

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use SoapClient;

class InsuranceController extends Controller
{
    function createBooking($wsdl){
        $ws  = new SoapClient($wsdl);
        $ret  = $ws->transaction($xml);
```

I get this error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

I tried adding it in app.php

```
'SoapClient' => SoapClient::class
```

and I also tried using \SoapClient() also, instead of SoapClient()

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your php installation is probably missing the SOAP extension. Please refer to this topic for more info: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Comment: thanks a lot, I added it in php.ini and restarted and it worked