# Laravel - Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, soap-client

I want to use SoapClient but it returns error: `Class 'SoapClient' not found`. I have windows+xampp and in my `php.ini` I coludn't find `;extension=php_soap.dll` to uncomment it in order to enable that so I added it in `extension=php_soap.dll`. It didn't work.
I created a new php file to use pure php code there: `var_dump(new SoapClient($url))` so it didn't return error but got result correctly. So I got that the problem might be from namespace but when I put a backslash before SoapClient, it should work isn't it?

And here is my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Gateways;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use \SoapClient;

class BankController extends GatewayController {
    public function requestGateway() {
        ...
        $client = new SoapClient($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Comment: Because I was using Laravel, I have used `php artisan serve` command. So when I stopped it with `ctrl+c` (Windows) and start it again it worked,