# Enabling Soap Client for docker docker-compose php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, soap, docker-compose, soap-client

I am developing a PHP SilverStripe CMS project. In my project, I am using SoapClient to consume Soap API. But when I initialize SoapClient class I got this error.

```
Class 'SoapClient' not found
```

I found out that I need to enable SoapClient for docker. Soap is installed/ enabled as in the screenshot below.

[image]

According to the accepted answer here I need to enable Soap Client and Soap Server as well. [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found). How can I do that? I am using docker-compose.yml. So whenever I run php command I just run like this, `docker-compose exec php-fpm composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for example [docker php-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/php-fpm/); You can build from that and add the build to your docker-compose.yaml.

The Dockerfile should look something like this:

```
FROM (NAMEOFIMAGE)
RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php && apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev php-soap && docker-php-ext-install soap
```

Alternatively, you can add the base image as a service and do the operations on the second line manually inside the container:

`docker exec -it container_identifier bash`

`rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php && apt-get update && apt-get install -y libxml2-dev php-soap && docker-php-ext-install soap`

then restart docker-compose.

Hope this helps somebody.