# Cannot get response from PHP Soapclient

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, soapserver

I am trying to fetch response from sending PHP SoapClient request. My understanding is that in Soap, the class exists on the Soap-server and is specified and fetched as an argument to Soapclient, pointing out the wsdl file.

I am using following link references:

Webservices:

- https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/index.htm
- https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/call/getAnnualAverageExchangeRates.htm

PHP Soapclient:

[How to make a PHP SOAP call using the SoapClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class)

---

**My code:**

```
<? php
$client = new SoapClient("https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl");

$params = array (
    "year" => 2010,
    "month" => 4
);

$response = $client->__soapCall('getAnnualAverageExchangeRates()', array($params));

var_dump($response);
```

**The error message:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /[path/Xxx.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /path/Xxx.php on line 4
    var_dump($response)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found

Comment: 1. the function wants three parameters, you only provide two. 2. Omit the brackets in the function name in __soapCall

Comment: The main problem was that I did not have soap installed. I do get another error but will open another question for better clarification.

Comment: It is working now. I ommited the brackets in the function name and added "languageid" in the params array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391442/fatal-error-class-soapclient-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to enable Soap extention from `php.ini`. Restart Apache. Then check `phpinfo()` to ensure extension is loaded.

```
$option = array('trace' => 1, 'keep_alive' => true,'connection_timeout' => 60);// add options here
$client = new SoapClient("https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl", $option);

$params = array (
    "year" => 2010,
    "month" => 4,
    "languageid" => 1 //language id may differ.
);

// you can directly call function from  wsdl.
$response = $client->getAnnualAverageExchangeRates(array($params));

var_dump($response);
```