# Can not install php7.4-soap on Debian 9

Tags: php, soap, debian, php-7.4, debian-stretch

I am using Debian 9, and I recently upgraded PHP from 5.6 to 7.4. I was hit by the

> Class 'SoapClient' not found

error when running an old PHP script, which worked very well under PHP 5.6. The `phpinfo()` lists "SOAP" module but it doesn't have a dedicated "soap" section with "Soap Client" listed (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391550)).

I believe the problem is that I have not installed the php7.4-soap extension, so I run `sudo apt-get install php7.4-soap`, but I got these errors:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-soap : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.20-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 7.4.16-1+0~20210305.42+debian9~1.gbpbbe65e is to be installed
               Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried installing php7.4-common manually, but the installation failed with these errors:

```
 php7.4-common : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libffi8ubuntu1 (>= 3.4~20200819) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I resolve this kind of problem? Thank you.

My output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` is:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:4:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-apt-config
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:5:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.6
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:6:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-tools
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:8:deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.6
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list:1:deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list:2:deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1:deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list:17:deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list:18:deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch main
/etc/apt/sources.list:20:deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:21:deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:24:deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch-updates main
/etc/apt/sources.list:25:deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch-updates main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On debian the `php7.4-soap` is available for  [bullseye and sid](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/php7.4-soap).

On debian Stretch, you can install `php7.4-soap` from [Sury repo](https://deb.sury.org/):

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https software-properties-common lsb-release ca-certificates
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4-soap
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I followed your steps, they all run well except the last step "sudo apt install php7.4-soap", which gives the same error message as the one in my question: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-soap : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.20-1+ubuntu21.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 7.4.16-1+0~20210305.42+debian9~1.gbpbbe65e is to be installed
               Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: @GavinDelaney Could you add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` to your question, let's make sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is correctly configured.

Comment: I just appended the output to my question, thank you.

Comment: @GavinDelaney `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list` then `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` then try to install the package. then copy the code in my answer and past it in the terminal.

Comment: thank you and it works! So the problem was that I have old source for wheezy in my source list.