# Class "SoapClient" not found on php 8

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, soap

I'm using PHP Version 8.0.14, and Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my AWS EC2.

My Loaded Configuration File is located here `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini`

and in my `php.ini` i have soap enabled

`extension=soap` (removed the `;`)

Even after restarting my Apache i still get the error `Class "SoapClient" not found`.

I thought maybe i didn't have Soap installed, so i tried `sudo apt-get install php-soap` and got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-soap is already the newest version (2:8.1+92+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

in my php code, the Soap is called like this

```
use SoapClient;

class bla {

 function abc() {
   $x = new SoapClient('https://url/?wsdl'); 
 }
}
```

any idea how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: [`apt install -y php8.0-soap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65051810/5897602)

Comment: @Jaquarh got it! thank you

Comment: Note: on Ubuntu 22.04, `php8.0-soap` is broken and not installed; you will need to add a PPA to get the package. I recommend using Ondrej's PHP PPA, which is the 'gold standard' of PHP PPAs: `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: @AlexanderTraikov glad to be helpful!